# underscore.js in Laravel Webpack is not recognize by PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, underscore.js, webstorm

Could help me with this problem, it is frustrating for me. I have started a project with Laravel in which I want to use underscore.js

In **resources/js/app.js** file I have the following content:

```
import jquery from "jquery";
import popper from "popper.js";
import underscore from "underscore";

try {
    window.$ = jquery;
    window._ = underscore;
    window.Popper = popper.default;

    require('bootstrap');
    require('./functions');
} catch (e) {
}
```

in this same directory, I have another file called `functions.js` which at the time of calling underscore.js PhpStorm points out the following error. Could you please help me? Thank you very much in advance

[image]

Why is PhpStorm asking me to import the library when it is already imported into the `app.js` file?

**EDIT 1**

I do not want to use lodash in my project, in essence, what I want is to be able to use underscore.js in the same way I can do it with JQuery, look at this image, when I call JQuery, PHPStorm does not mark me any import error, however it does so with underscore.js

[image]

Comment: PhpStorm is correct here - you have to import all files required by each of your modules explicitly, adding imports to the main file won't work here. Node.js will throw ReferenceError unless you add a `require('lodash')` to your `functions.js`

Comment: Please, see EDIT 1

Comment: sorry, sure I meant `underscore`, not `lodash`. But anyway: if a library is defined as a es6 or commonjs module, it has to be imported explicitly using `import` or `require`; it's a bit strange that you import it in one of the files and don't import in the other